# Java - Xeiam's XChart Marker With Values

Tags: java, graph, charts, knowm-xchart

I've been trying to figure out if it is possible to put the exact value for each Bar/Line Marker.

Current Result :
[image]

Desired Result :
[image]

Comment: It's not possible. I added a feature request for it though!

Comment: Here's the feature request: https://github.com/timmolter/XChart/issues/112

Answer (score 0):

In Xchart library, to get the count of each bar use annotations.

```
CategoryChart chart = new CategoryChartBuilder()
            .yAxisTitle("ABC Title")
            .theme(Styler.ChartTheme.GGPlot2).build();

    //each stack count and total count of each bar
    chart.getStyler().setHasAnnotations(true);
    chart.getStyler().setShowTotalAnnotations(true);
    chart.getStyler().setAnnotationsPosition(1);
```